Can the United States Government ban access to certain websites/services?
Can the United States of America ban its citizens from access to certain websites?
For instance, if the government wanted to ban Yandex, TikTok, or some other website could they ban it? Would it be in violation of the first amendment?
Edit: To clarify, I am referencing to the banning of communication/access between certain websites and US citizens—not the takedown of certain websites hosted on US soil.

Without knowing the reason for the ban, it is impossible to know. Some reasons are valid ones, others are not. There is no one categorical answer to this question at the level of generality at which it has been posed in this question.

Internet censorship in the United States

You haven't provided the reason for the proposed ban, but there are definitely some cases in which it allowed. For example, the Russian Ministry of Defense website is banned by the US government.
